# Azure Web App Performance Test

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Noticed a Performance Test feature on Azure Web Apps.

Appreciate if I can get clarification on below:

1. Is it possible to test multiple pages?
2. Possible to specify which page**s** to test?
3. Possible to test the login state of the user so that performance test including backend API call etc?

Answer (score 1):

1. Each test only test on a single URL.
2. Can specify which URL to test.
3. Only HTTP GET requests can be made from tests. If API calls depend on tokens in the URL only, they can be tested by this feature.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can create a WebTest with Visual Studio to test multiple pages and have specific validations.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182536(v=vs.90).aspx. Once created, you can upload as the test
   [image]
2. Yes, see #1
3. Yes, the WebTest will record all steps and reproduce them, cookies and all.